# What's the best way to seamlessly link back to an android app from a browser?

Tags: android, browser, android-browser

I'm an Android newbie, in the planning stages of a project that involves android.  I'm considering augmenting an android app with a button on a menu page linking to an HTML5 page, which leads to a sequence of pages, and ideally returning to the android app's menu page, via a button on the last page.  I'd create an intent filter in my app to intercept a URL request and show the app instead.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the web page in a WebView in your app, you could [inject a js interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) and interact directly with your java code through it. Otherwise, yes, a custom url scheme and an Intent filter would probably be the best way to go around it.